# Group multi-dimensional array after unwinding elements

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Again with mongoDB. I really like aggregation, but still can't "get it".

So here is my array:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55951b2bf41edfc80b00002a"),
    "orders" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "55929142f41edfdc0f00002f",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "id_basket" : 1,
        "card" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "type" : "9cf4161002b9eda349bb9c5ae64b9f4a",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "type" : "9cf4161002b9eda349bb9c5ae64b9f4a",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "full_amount" : "40",
    },
    {
        "id" : "55929142f41edfdc0f00002f",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "id_basket" : 1,
        "card" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "type" : "9cf4161002b9eda349bb9c5ae64b9f4a",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "type" : "9cf4161002b9eda349bb9c5ae64b9f4a",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : {
                            "name" : "Normal",
                            "price" : "10",
                            "price_disp" : "10 &euro;",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "full_amount" : "40",
    },
],
"rate" : "0.23",
"date" : "2015-07-02 13:04:34",
"id_user" : 97,
}
```

I want to output something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55951b2bf41edfc80b00002a"),
    "orders" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "55929142f41edfdc0f00002f",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "card" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "full_amount" : "40",
    },
    {
        "id" : "55929142f41edfdc0f00002f",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "card" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000030",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "full_amount" : "40",
    },
],
"rate" : "0.23",
"date" : "2015-07-02 13:04:34",
}
```

I've tried many combinations with unwinding, projecting and grouping and failed to get what I want. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be using the aggregation framework for tasks like this that do not actually "aggregate" anything between documents. This really is a "projection" task since all you are asking is to "alter" the structure of a document, and that is a task probably better suited to coding in the client after the document is retrieved.

A very good reason for this is that operations like [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) are **very costly** in terms of performance. What `$unwind` does is produce a "copy" of the document content for each array member present, which results in a lot more documents to process.

Think of that like a "SQL Join" with a "one to many" relationship, the only difference being the data is self contained in one document. Processing `$unwind` simulates the "join" results in that the "master" (one) document contents are reproduced for every "child" (many) document.

In order to counter such operations being done by people, MongoDB 2.6 introduced the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator, which processes array elements within the document itself.

So instead of doing multiple ( or any ) `$unwind` actions, you can instead just process the arrays within the document itself using `$map` in a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "orders": { "$map": {
      "input": "$orders",
      "as": "o",
      "in": {
        "id": "$$o.id",
        "name": "$$o.name",
        "card": { "$map": {
          "input": "$$o.card",
          "as": "c",
          "in": {
            "id": "$$c.id",
            "serial": "$$c.serial",
            "name": "$$c.name",
            "ticket": { "$map": {
              "input": "$$c.ticket",
              "as": "t",
              "in": {
                "id": "$$t.id",
                "name": "$$t.name",
                "price": "$$t.price.price_disp"
              }
            }}
          }
        }},
        "full_amount": "$$o.full_amount"
      }    
    }},
    "rate": 1,
    "date": 1
  }}
])
```

The operations are fairly simple there as each "array" is assigned it's own variable name, and for a simple projection operation such as this all that is really left is selecting which fields you want.

In earlier versions, processing using `$unwind` is much more difficult:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$orders" },
  { "$unwind": "$orders.card" },
  { "$unwind": "$orders.card.ticket" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "_id": "$_id",
      "orders": {
        "id": "$orders.id",
        "name": "$orders.name",
        "card": {
          "id": "$orders.card.id",
          "serial": "$orders.card.serial",
          "name": "$orders.card.name"
        },
        "full_amount": "$orders.full_amount"
      },
      "rate": "$rate",
      "date": "$date"
    },
    "ticket": { 
      "$push": {
        "id": "$orders.card.ticket.id",
        "name": "$orders.card.ticket.name",
        "price": "$orders.card.ticket.price.price_disp"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { 
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "orders": {
        "id": "$_id.orders.id",
        "name": "$_id.orders.name",
        "full_amount": "$_id.orders.full_amount"
      },
      "rate": "$_id.rate",
      "date": "$_id.date"
    },
    "card": { 
      "$push": {
        "id": "$_id.orders.card.id",
        "serial": "$_id.orders.card.serial",
        "name": "$_id.orders.card.name",
        "ticket": "$ticket"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id._id",
    "orders": { 
      "$push": {
        "id": "$_id.orders.id",
        "name": "$_id.orders.name",
        "card": "$card",
        "full_amount": "$_id.orders.full_amount"
      }
    },
    "rate": { "$first": "$_id.rate" },
    "date": { "$first": "$_id.date" }
  }}
])
```

So following through that carefully, you should see that since you `$unwind` three times it is necessary to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) *"three times"* as well, while carefully grouping all the distinct values at each "level" and re-constructing the arrays via [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

This really is not advised **at all** as was mentioned earlier:

- You *"are not **grouping/aggregating** anything"* and each sub-document **"must"** contain a *"unique"* itentifier because of the "grouping" operations required to re-construct arrays. ( See: **NOTE** )
- The `$unwind` operation here is **very costly**. All of the document information is re-produced by a factor of "n" array X "n" array elements and so on. So there is much more data in the aggregation pipeline than your collection or query selection actually contains in itself.

Therefore in conclusion, for the general processing of "reformatting your data" you should instead be processing each document in your code rather than be "throwing it" at the aggregation pipeline to do.

If your document data requires "sufficient" manipulation that makes a "substantial difference" to the returned result size that you deem to be more efficient than pulling the whole document and manipulating in the client, then and "only" then should you be using the `$project` form as shown with the `$map` operations.

---

### Sidebar

Your original "tag" here mentions "PHP".

All MongoDB queries including the aggregation have nothing language specific about them and are just "data structures" and are represented as such mostly in the "native form" for those languages (PHP,JavaScript,python,etc), and with "builder methods" for those languages without "native" expressive formats for free structures ( C,C#,Java ).

In all cases, there are simple parsers available for JSON, which is a common "linqua franca" here as the MongoB Shell itself is JavaScript based and understands JSON structre ( as actual JavaScript Objects ) natively.

So when working with such examples use tools like:

- [**json_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php): to get more of an insight into how your native data structure is constructed.
- [**json_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): in order to check your native data structure against any JSON represented sample.

All content here is just simple "key/value" `array()` notation, though nested. But it is probably good practice to be aware of the tools and use them regularly.

---

### **NOTE:**

The data sample you give looks very much like you have "cut and paste" data in order to create multiple items, as various "sub-items" all share the same "id" values.

Your "real" data **should not** do this! So I hope it does not, but if so then fix it.

In order to make the second example workable ( first is perfectly fine as is ) the data needs to be altered to included "unique" "id" values for each sub-element.

As I used here:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55951b2bf41edfc80b00002a"),
    "orders" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "55929142f41edfdc0f00002a",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "card" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "250",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000031",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000032",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "251",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000033",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000034",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "full_amount" : "40",
    },
    {
        "id" : "55929142f41edfdc0f00002b",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "card" : [ 
            {
                "id" : "252",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000035",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000036",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id" : "253",
                "serial" : "B",
                "name" : "Eco",
                "ticket" : [ 
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000037",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    },
                    {
                        "id" : "55927d41f41edfd00f000038",
                        "name" : "ZZZ",
                        "price" : "10 &euro;"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "full_amount" : "40",
    }
    ],
    "rate" : "0.23",
    "date" : "2015-07-02 13:04:34",
}
```

Comment: Guys/Gals like You are the reason to ask questions at stackoverflow. Thank you very much for great reply. It works perfectly. As I wrote I am stiil a noob in mongoDB. Didn't knew about $map. It's really easy. PS. I know about ids, just pasted to make fast example.

Comment: @user3816436 Thanks, and glad you said "Gal" coz it is. It did look like cut & paste so I did mention that. It does help though if people looking at your question can simply "cut & paste" themselves and work with the data without needing to correct problems. That was the general future tip. Make it easy for people to test and use and you are likely to get a reasonable response.